# Deleting and undeleting a question

Tags: discussion

I have just now put a question on the site.

Despite getting a vote from someone I have decided that I did not work on it by myself long enough, and decided to delete it - at least temporarily, until I either give up again or reach a solution (and then decide whether or not to endow the site with the question and the solution, as the question is somewhere on the SQL at the moment and someone did give a vote on the question implying it is somewhat interesting).

Suppose in an hour, a day or a week, I have decided to give up and seek for help on this site (which is essentially as knocking on the doors of other students and professors - only online), I would like to edit and undelete the question - as to not draw extraneous reputation from the community that will later be removed by rep. re-calc in several months (and thus possibly inflate my reputation for a while).

Luckily, at the moment I have the link with the question open, however it exits no more in my profile, nor if I tried to access it from cached pages.

What am I to do if and when I give up again?

(I actually managed to answer my own question, but some other question remain open...)

Comment: A very interesting fact is that while deleting the edit that I made was saved, yet I was notified that the page I was asking for does not exist. Weird :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can see arbitrary deleted questions until 10k+ rep. It'll probably be easiest for you to ask a moderator to undelete it (again, not perfect, but flagging an arbitrary question works).

Comment: In that case if you can undelete it for me, it would be great. Luckily I saved the edits on my computer so I can easily restore it. Many thanks!